# How to create constexpr functions in c++

Tags: c++

I am reading *Programming Principles and Practice Using C++* written by Bjarne Stroustrup, and I am stuck at page 204, about constexpr, seems like I cannot make the code example in the book compile:

```
constexpr double xscale = 10;
constexpr double yscale = 0.8;
constexpr Point scalePoint(Point p)
{
    return{ xscale * p.x, yscale * p.y };
}
```

Point is a class with two members, x y, and a constructor:

```
class Point
{
    double x;
    double y;
    Point(double inX, double inY)
        : x(inX),y(inY)
    {

    } 
};
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Error (active)      
function "scalePoint" (declared at line 13) was previously not declared constexpr
```

Comment: *Where* do you get the error? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, including how you call the function.

Comment: If you are returning a `Point`, you might want to make the constructor `constexpr` as well.

Comment: The error makes it sound as if you have a prototype of `scalePoint` somewhere outside the code you posted which is declared without `constexpr`.

Comment: Most compilers will tell you where the previous declaration was. Read on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commenter Bo pointed out correctly, you must make the constructor of Point constexpr too. Constexpr functions can only call other constexpr functions!

In addition, you have only private Members in class Point. So function scalePoint() cannot access p.x, p.y and cannot create an instance of Point as a return value because the constructor is private.

Make Point a struct or add a "public:" statement:

```
struct Point
{
    double x;
    double y;
    constexpr Point(double inX, double inY)
        : x(inX),y(inY)
    {

    } 
};
```

That compiles for me.